# Fit entire Google Map in zoom level in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have a google map with a bunch of coordinates

```
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-37.813047, 144.959911))
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-37.814895, 144.960759))
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-37.814361, 144.963140))
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-37.812386, 144.962239))
```

I would like the map to be automatically zoomed to the best level based on the points however I can't find anything relating to this.

I have this working:

```
var vancouver = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-37.813047, 144.959911)
var calgary = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-37.814361, 144.963140)
var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: vancouver, coordinate: calgary)
var camera = viewMap.cameraForBounds(bounds, insets:UIEdgeInsetsZero)
viewMap.camera = camera
```

however it only accepts 2 coordinates where I may have up to 100

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `GMSCoordinateBounds(path:)` to fit all coordinates. But it will display a `world size scale` if you update the camera right after your another update. So you can use `dispatch_after` to solve the problem.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-37.813047, longitude: -72.8561644, zoom:5)
        mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera:camera)

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = camera.target
        marker.snippet = "Hello World"
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
        marker.map = mapView

        self.view = mapView

        delay(seconds: 2) { () -> () in
            let path = GMSMutablePath()
            path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.36, -122.0))
            path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.45, -122.0))
            path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.45, -122.2))
            path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.36, -122.2))
            path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.36, -122.0))

            let rectangle = GMSPolyline(path: path)
            rectangle.map = self.mapView

            let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)

            self.mapView!.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds, withPadding: 15.0))
        }
    }
```

The `delay` method uses the `dispatch_after`:

```
func delay(#seconds: Double, completion:()->()) {
    let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64( Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * seconds ))

    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your points. The southwest corner is the minimum latitude and longitude. The northeast corner is the maximum latitude and longitude. Once you have those two points, pass them into your cameraForBounds method.

Answer (score -1):

Try finding an optimal viewing box on google maps by:

-Clicking on the north east corner of the area you think will cover the coordinates in a browser. Note the lat & long.

-Then click the south east corner in the same area which you think will enclose all the coordinates & note the lat & long.

Put the latitudes & longitudes in the respective variables of the below code:

```
var southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitide,longititude)
var northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude)
var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
var camera = mapView.cameraForBounds(bounds, insets:UIEdgeInsetsZero)
mapView.camera = camera;
```